# Is it possile to add links under Tools section of Accounts tab

Tags: visualforce, account, tools

can we add links under tools section of Accounts tab.Currently there are 4-5 links already available.Can we customize tools section of Accounts tab.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You would need to roll out your own solution such as a custom Visualforce page to replace the Accounts tab etc.